# Prevent premature wear of SD-card when repeatedly writing to a file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, sd-card

I am collecting data from an external device in a Raspberry Pi, 4 bytes at time at about ~100 samples/sec. The data is written to the SD-card where the OS is installed.

Currently, I am using the following code:

```py
with open('data.dat', 'ab') as f:
    while True:
        sample_word = read_sample() # read 32 bits from a peripheral
        f.write(sample_word.to_bytes(4, 'big'))
```

Since the data collection will run for a few weeks, I do not want to wear out the SD-card by continuously writing to the same block(s). The [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function have a buffering parameter which suggests that I do not need to add custom logic for buffering:

> buffering is an optional integer used to set the buffering policy. Pass 0 to switch buffering off (only allowed in binary mode), 1 to select line buffering (only usable in text mode), and an integer > 1 to indicate the size in bytes of a fixed-size chunk buffer. When no buffering argument is given, the default buffering policy works as follows:
>
> - Binary files are buffered in fixed-size chunks; the size of the buffer is chosen using a heuristic trying to determine the underlying device’s “block size” and falling back on io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE. On many systems, the buffer will typically be 4096 or 8192 bytes long.

Does the heuristic make a good job at guessing the SD card block size? `io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE` is 8k. Is it safer to pass a size to the buffing parameter? If yes, what is the optimal size for recent SD-cards?

Comment: Assuming the native block size for the SD card is 512 or 4096 bytes, any multiple thereof (such as 8192) should also be fine. However, I think there's also file system overhead and buffering to take into consideration here...

Comment: Also, if you don't mind the possibility of losing data if e.g. power fails or falters, you could just set the buffer to "large enough" - that way you'd likely, given this append-only scenario, not touch the same block twice anyway.

Comment: @AKX SD cards go to great lengths to emulate a reasonable block size, the actual blocks are much larger than you'd expect.

Comment: @MarkRansom Alright. :) The more you know, etc. :)

Comment: @MarkRansom Will writing to chunks of the emulated length (e.g. 512) vs. native length affect the wearing of the SD-card?

Comment: The wearing is based on the physical structure of the blocks, not on the emulation.  In fact it can make things worse, writing to 2 consecutive emulated blocks might trigger 2 physical writes to the physical block where only 1 was strictly necessary.

Comment: Do you have a rule of thumb for modern SDXC cards for physical block size?

Comment: Check out [What's the life expectancy of an SD card?](https://superuser.com/questions/17350/whats-the-life-expectancy-of-an-sd-card).  which indicates the card will withstand about 100,000 write cycles and most cards contain wear=leveling circuitry to spread the writes evenly across all blocks.